# Force first item to show onclick in an Array splice

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

I have managed to cobble this together with my limited js skills (I got the array splice working) and some help here (the prev-next nav).

The issue I'm having is the first item from the newly invoked array does not show immediately onclick. You have to first select the category/subject (animals, vehicles, etc.), and *then* click one of the nav arrows.

```html
<head>
  <style>
    [onclick] {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="box">fruits</div>
  <button type="button" onclick="prev()">&#11207;</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="next()">&#11208;</button>

  <script>
    var fruits = ["apple", "banana", "orange"];
    var vehicles = ["car", "bus", "truck"];
    var body = ["eye", "ear", "nose"];
    var animals = ["lion", "tiger", "elephant"];

    var box = document.getElementById('box');
    var i = -1;

    function next() {
      i = i >= fruits.length - 1 ? 0 : i + 1;
      box.innerHTML = fruits[i];
    }

    function prev() {
      i = i > 0 ? i - 1 : fruits.length - 1;
      box.innerHTML = fruits[i];
    }
  </script>

  <script>
    function veh() {
      fruits = vehicles.slice(0);
    }

    function bod() {
      fruits = body.slice(0);
    }

    function ani() {
      fruits = animals.slice(0);
    }
  </script>
  <br/>
  <p onclick="veh()">vehicles</p>
  <p onclick="bod()">body</p>
  <p onclick="ani()">animals</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can automatically use function next() to choose array

```
function veh() {
  fruits = vehicles.slice(0);
  next()
}
```

```html
<head>
  <style>
    [onclick] {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="box">fruits</div>
  <button type="button" onclick="prev()">&#11207;</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="next()">&#11208;</button>

  <script>
    var fruits = ["apple", "banana", "orange"];
    var vehicles = ["car", "bus", "truck"];
    var body = ["eye", "ear", "nose"];
    var animals = ["lion", "tiger", "elephant"];

    var box = document.getElementById('box');
    var i = -1;

    function next() {
      i = i >= fruits.length - 1 ? 0 : i + 1;
      box.innerHTML = fruits[i];
    }

    function prev() {
      i = i > 0 ? i - 1 : fruits.length - 1;
      box.innerHTML = fruits[i];
    }
  </script>

  <script>
    function veh() {
      fruits = vehicles.slice(0);
      next()
    }

    function bod() {
      fruits = body.slice(0);
      next()
    }

    function ani() {
      fruits = animals.slice(0);
      next()
    }
  </script>
  <br/>
  <p onclick="veh()">vehicles</p>
  <p onclick="bod()">body</p>
  <p onclick="ani()">animals</p>
</body>
```

Comment: This seems like the best solution since the syntax will be the same in every case, rather than having to restate the name of the target array.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you)

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly normal. Changing the `fruits` variable will not automatically cause the DOM to update. You have to write the code for that.

In this case, you need to set `box.innerHTML`. So for example, in your `veh` event handler you would write `box.innerHTML = vehicles[0]`, provided you want to display the first item in the array.

```
function veh() {
  fruits = vehicles.slice(0);
  box.innerHTML = vehicles[0];
}
```

The problem you are facing is called "data binding" and is a classic problem of frontend development.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's behavior of the DOM because when you change the variable directly to the javascript the DOM page doesn't automatically change.

If you want to also change the html you should also put `box.innerHTML = fruits[0];` in below of  `veh()` `bod()` and `ani()` function. So it looks like this.

```
function bod() {
  fruits = vehicles.slice(0);
  box.innerHTML = fruits[0];
}
```